# If an active activity go to background, will I receive a message?

Tags: android

I want to do some operation before my activity go to background. Is there a message I can register?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it goes in the bg, `onPause()` of the Activity will be called.

Please admire this diagram :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The method `onPause()` is called when something takes user interaction, but your activty is still SEEN behind.

The method `onStop()` is called when your activity is stopped - its not seen on screen anyore, and does not take user interaction.

The method `onDestroy()` is called when your activity is destroyed, here you should do final cleanups.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to write your code onPause() of your activity

```
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();

   //your code..
}
```